# I need clic twice or cannot get the the data form

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I have the following problem.

If I put he JavaScript code into the `head` or `body` tag, I need to click twice the submit button and then the Ajax form or whatever I need to do it does correctly, but I need to click twice.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>XXXX</title>

    <!--Este es el JS que hace que funcione Phonegap-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>    

    <!--JS específicos de Jquery Mobile-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 

    <!--Estos son script creados para la aplicacion-->
    <script src="js/md5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>

    <!--CSS del tema que he creado para apotecalia-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/XXXX.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />  

</head>
<div id="login">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   

        <form id="check-user" data-ajax="false">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label> Usuario </label>
                    <input type="text" id="correo" name="correo">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label> Contrase&ntilde;a </label>
                    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" >
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Acceder" name="enviar" id="enviar">

</fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Login.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#enviar').click( function() {
if($('#correo').val().length > 0 && $('#pwd').val().length > 0){
alert($('#correo').val() + $('#pwd').val());    
    } 
 });
});
```

But if I put the script code into the tag page where I need to use it, I don't need to click twice, but I cannot get the data form to do my Ajax request.

The same code, but if I put the script code into `data-role="page"` I have to put this code into all the tags... The alert in this case is empty.

```
<div id="login">
 <script src="js/login.js"></script>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
```

Please I don't know how to do it, I tried two weeks fixing this, I need your help.

Comment: I think I have the solution, all the JavaScript code, that I create for my app, must be into data-role="page" not in head tag.In that case <script src="js/md5.js"></script><script src="js/login.js"></script> must be after <form id="check-user" data-ajax="false">  could it be the origin of my problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add simple ***type="button"*** instead of ***type="submit"*** .

```
<input type="button" data-role="button" value="Acceder" name="enviar" id="enviar">

$(function () {

  $('#enviar').click( function() {       

      if($('#correo').val().length > 0 && $('#pwd').val().length > 0){
         alert($('#correo').val() + $('#pwd').val());

        // Add code here submit form data using Ajax 

        var ajax_call = your_serviceURL;                  
        var str = $('#check-user').serialize();  

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: ajax_call,
             data: str,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(response){                              
                  // It's success json response
              }
        }).done(function() {

        }) 

      }

   });
});
```

Comment: Ok,at last I got the alert, but now I need to do an ajax request into this JavaScript code but It does´t work, only if I click twice. This is very strange

Comment: You are using jquery mobile but according to this your page is not structured.

Answer (score 0):

Include your script in the `head` tag.

Declare your page container `<div data-role="page" id="login">`.

Change your code in `login.js` to:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#login", function(event, ui)
{
    $(document).on("click", "#enviar", function(event)
    {
        if ($('#correo').val().length > 0 && $('#pwd').val().length > 0)
            alert($('#correo').val() + $('#pwd').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this code, It could be the solution, but now I have this error: 07-14 12:56:18.390: E/Web Console(28534): Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/login.js:1

Comment: you have to include your script after jQuery

Comment: Sorry, I was testing and I switched places that piece of code, but still have the same problem, I need to click twice. This will drive me crazy.

Comment: try changing `enviar` button to `<a href="#" data-role="button" id="enviar">Acceder</a>`

Comment: It does not seem to do anything :(